# Is it possible to concatenate using STRING_AGG on an array that was created with SPLIT() IN BigQuery

Tags: split, google-bigquery, unnest, string-agg

I am trying to use string_agg to concatenate an array that was created using SPLIT().

The code for the array I'm trying to concatenate looks like this:

```
ARRAY (
   SELECT AS STRUCT
     SPLIT(CustomField.SubComponents, ' | ') AS Name
 ) AS SubComponents,
```

I have unnested Supcomponents in my Joins using `LEFT JOIN UNNEST (Subcomponents) AS Subcomponents`

However, I am getting the following error:
`No matching signature for aggregate function STRING_AGG for argument types: ARRAY <STRING>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured this out, I had to UNNEST twice, once as `LEFT JOIN UNNEST (Subcomponents) AS Subcomponents`

AND then again as `LEFT JOIN UNNEST (SubComponents.Name) AS SubComponentsName`

This allowed me to use string_agg succesfully.